# What's the use of mailCatcher?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring bot application , i want to send notification to my user's gmail account , i found many useful tutorial about that , so i tried working on it ..

But i saw in some forum that i should use mailCatcher instead , i tried to understand what it stands for but there is a lot of a little bit different explanations .

So my questions are :

do i really need MailCatcher ?

As i know mailcatcher can only help us debug and see our messages sent even thought these emails doesnt exists in reality , isnt it ?

Does MailCatcher catches mails and deliver it again for exemple to gmail accounts ? ( supposed im using real emails..) ?

Using gmail api pushs us to activate some security condition in our account for the whole app as i saw in some questions .. , how can we avoid that , or is it necassery ?

I wish i could get some good answers about this.

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. To send mail, you dont' need MailCatcher.

MailCatcher is used to check whether you are going to send correct mails.

> MailCatcher runs a super simple SMTP server which catches any message sent to it to display in a web interface. Run mailcatcher, set your favourite app to deliver to smtp://127.0.0.1:1025 instead of your default SMTP server, then check out http://127.0.0.1:1080 to see the mail that's arrived so far.

To send email, you need another server, which can really send mail for you, and an account on the sever. You can run this sever by your self, or use public server, like google. But do please not send spams.

On the other hand

> send notification to my user's gmail account

doesn't means "send mail". You should consider, do you send email, or just notification.

Comment: Ah i see , what i want , is when an action happends in my application , i send to some users an email to their gmail accounts so they can know that this action happend , it's like a notification.

Comment: Another question does MailCache == MailCatcher ? Are we talking about the same thing ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the misleading typo. For the "application", is this a website, a mobile app, or something else? Because they would be different to consider how to send "notification"

Comment: It's a web application , i'm working with angular5 in front end , and spring-boot in backend , what i did is : when this action happends i select some users's email so i send to them an email with the same content : 'this action is happened for exemple '

Comment: I think the backend is a good place to send the email. Call the mail API provided by Google or whichever company you like, with your account.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i did , in back end i send to these users the email , so this is considered as notification right .